# Use XML resource in List Fragment generated with Eclipse

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I've generated a new List Fragment using Eclipse (*New -> Android Object -> New List Fragment*) which creates `ItemFragment` and `dummy.DummyContent` Classes.

I have 2 questions regarding this:

1. More of a general question... How is the DummyContent instantiated? Is the declaration of the ArrayAdapter doing the work? As I don't see anywhere in the code a new DummyContent. see below:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   // TODO: Change Adapter to display your content
   mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(),
           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
           DummyContent.ITEMS);
   }
   ```
2. In the DummyContent class, I would like to populate the `ArrayList<DummyItem> ITEMS` with data pulled from a Resource XML file, however it seems since I don't the `Context` in this DummyContent class, I can't access `R.xml.*` Is there a way to pass the context to that class somehow?

   ```
   public class DummyContent {

   /**
    * An array of sample (dummy) items.
    */
    public static List<DummyItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<DummyItem>();

   /**
    * A map of sample (dummy) items, by ID.
    */
    public static Map<String, DummyItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, DummyItem>();

    static {
       // Add 3 sample items.
            addItem(new DummyItem("1", "Item 1"));
            addItem(new DummyItem("2", "Item 2"));
            addItem(new DummyItem("3", "Item 3"));
   }

   private static void addItem(DummyItem item) {
       ITEMS.add(item);
       ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
   }

   /**
    * A dummy item representing a piece of content.
    */
   public static class DummyItem {
       public String id;
       public String content;

       public DummyItem(String id, String content) {
           this.id = id;
       this.content = content;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
               return content;
       }
   }
   }
   ```

Thanks in advance and let me know if there is anything unclear in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> More of a general question... How is the DummyContent instantiated? Is
>   the declaration of the ArrayAdapter doing the work? As I don't see
>   anywhere in the code a new DummyContent.

It isn't instantiated, all of its fields and methods are `static` meaning they could be referenced without the need of an instance of that class. Have a look at any doc/tutorial about static classes/field/methods for more information.

> In the DummyContent class, I would like to populate the
>   ArrayList ITEMS with data pulled from a Resource XML file,
>   however it seems since I don't the Context in this DummyContent class,
>   I can't access R.xml.* Is there a way to pass the context to that
>   class somehow?

One option is to keep the current `DummyContent` class and do the xml parsing at the fragment level and just pass the parsed data to the `DummyContent` class.

To pass the `Context` to your `DummyContent` class create a constructor for it like below:

```
public class DummyContent {

    private Context mContext;

    public DummyContent(Context context) {
         mContext = context;
    } 
    //...
```

You'll be then be able to do:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DummyContent dc = new DummyContent(getActivity()); 
    // do the parsing in the DummyContent: dc.doParsing()
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
        DummyContent.ITEMS); // assuming that you keep the ITEMS ArrayList static
}
```